About StoreLoad Memory Barrier
I don't understand StoreLoad.
Does store1 StoreLoad load2 mean that the CPU's store instruction cannot be reordered after StoreLoad and the load instruction cannot be reordered before StoreLoad?
If that's the case, does it mean that the load instruction can be sorted after StoreLoad and the store instruction can be sorted before StoreLoad?

Yes, if you had load ; StoreLoad ; store, a pure StoreLoad barrier would allow reordering of the load and store.  Is that what you meant?  You said "the load instruction", but the only example you gave had the load after the store already.  BTW, on most real CPUs, StoreLoad is only available as part of a full barrier that blocks all 4 kinds of reordering because it's the most expensive one to block.  (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/ / https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/)

I was struggling with fences a lot as well. First; fences are not a replacement for the JMM: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane. So if you want to understand the JMM by looking at fences, you will be in a lot of trouble (been there, done that).
Apart from the [LoadLoad][LoadStore][StoreLoad][StoreStore] ordering guarantees, a fence can be 1-way or 2-way.
A 1-way fence will only order in 1 direction e.g a volatile load will only prevent later loads/stores from being reordered with that volatile load, but it will not prevent earlier loads/stores from being reordered with that volatile load.
This is demonstrated below:
plain_a=1 (1)
r1=volatile_b; (2)
r2=plain_c; (3)
plain_d=2 (4)

So (3) and (4) can't be ordered before (2), but (1) can be reordered after (2), (3) and (4).
In Java this is called roach-motel semantics. This also applies to locks; so loads/stores can move into a synchronized block, but not over/out of it.
A 2-way fence will order loads/stores in both directions. E.g. a VarHandle.storeStoreFence will prevent stores on both sides of the fence from being reordered.
plain_a=1; (1)
storeStoreFence() (2)
plain_b=1; (3)

(1) and (3) are guaranteed to be performed in this order. (1) can't move in front of (3) and (3) can't move before (1).

One-way reordering restrictions are only attached to operations (load, store, or the load or store side of an RMW); things we actually call fences are stand-alone 2-way barriers (otherwise they wouldn't work).  So I dislike the terminology of a "1 way fence"; call it an "acquire operation" or "release operation". (https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).  In terms of Java, Shipilёv says the JMM formalism talks about "actions", so we can e.g. say an "acquire action".
